# copy row to new worksheet to next available row

Tags: excel, vba

How would you copy a row and paste it to the next available row to another worksheet. Currently the code below only pastes according to the entry row of the mastersheet.

```
Sub ShowMonth()

     Dim k As Long
  
     For k = 2 To 9999

     Cells(k, 14).Value = Month(Cells(k, 1).Value)
     
   
  Next k

End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub Move()
        Dim MonthNo As Range
        Dim lastrow, j As Long
        
        Set MonthNo = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("N2:N9999")
        lastrow = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
        For j = 2 To 9999
            If MonthNo(j) = 1 Then
                lastrow = lastrow + 1
                MonthNo(j).Rows.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Jan").Range("A" & lastrow)
            ElseIf MonthNo(j) = 2 Then
                lastrow = lastrow + 1
                MonthNo(j).Rows.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Feb").Range("A" & lastrow)    
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please put in some efforts to put your complete code? Your `If` doesn't have an `End If`. Your `For` doesn't have a `Next` and your `Sub` doesn't have and `End Sub`. How are we even supposed to edit the post.. forget about helping you....

Comment: How do you make the code into that format? Sorry, but I am trying.

Comment: No worries. i edited it for you. Now can you explain why are you looping from 2 to 9999? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do. Give me one moment. posting an answer

Comment: I am quite new to coding and I guess its just an easy way to loop through available entries. I would like to copy a row from a master sheet if it fits the criteria and paste it to the next available row on the corresponding sheet(month) but now it is pasting it on the "lastrow" (entry row on the mastersheet) which causes lots of blanks on the monthly sheets.

Comment: Quick question. Column N have numeric values like 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: yep, i didnt know how to get the month out of the date in the same code

Comment: thats ok. so that column has dates or number?

Comment: it has numbers, i used  - Dim k As Long -  
  
     For k = 2 To 9999 -

     Cells(k, 14).Value = Month(Cells(k, 1).Value)-

Comment: Posted an answer. Test it out and let me know if that is what you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented the code so that you should not have a problem understanding the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Move()
    Dim wsLrow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As String
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Set your worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("MasterSheet")
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col N
        wsLrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the cells in Col N
        For i = 2 To wsLrow
            Select Case .Range("N" & i).Value2
                Case 1: wsDest = "Jan"
                Case 2: wsDest = "Feb"
                Case 3: wsDest = "Mar"
                '
                ' And so on. Add more if applicable
                '
            End Select
            
            If wsDest <> "" Then
                With Worksheets(wsDest)
                    '~~> Find the row in the destination worksheet to copy
                    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    '~~> Copy the row from MasterSheet to relevant sheet
                    ws.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=.Rows(lastrow)
                End With
                wsDest = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Its great, thank you so much. Can i bother you one last time, how could i alter the code (i posted new code) so that if there was no date there would be no number 12 showing

Comment: Sorry I did not understand?

Comment: Do u know how to alter the new code i added (for extracting the date) that when there is no date entered nth will show up in the N coolumn

Comment: So Col A has date and you want to extract month from that?

Comment: Yes, but after i extract, if column a is blank, it will extract 12 and put it in column N

Comment: Why not put a formula in the relevant column? `=IF(A1="",12,MONTH(A1))`

Comment: `Select Case` could be replaced with `Choose`